# How to do drag and drop the folder using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-directive

I need to perform Drag and drop the folder,I have searched some sources,in that I found Angular file upload package, it helps me to upload multiple files but not able to upload folder. So is there any way to perform drag and drop the folder. It should support all browser

Comment: check this https://marcoliceti.github.io/angular-uploads/

Comment: Thank you for your response @AswinRamesh ..Its working but my concern is, it should be work in all browser.